# Xcode failing to update binary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm experiencing a very confusing issue with Xcode. It started when the debugger started skipping over some lines and stopping at the wrong lines on breakpoints. I tried adding NSLogs, but they weren't having any effect.

I restarted Xcode and did a clean build, and now no breakpoints fire anywhere, and NSLogs don't work either, even in `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. I've made sure that the current scheme is in Debug mode, so I don't know why this would be happening.

Has anyone else experienced something similar?

EDIT: Logs that were present before I started having this issue still work, but no new ones.

Comment: What happens if you clean your build and try to run it again?

Comment: Nothing different. No breakpoints work and nothing logs.

Comment: Try to restart your computer... I met a similar problem Yesterday and restart computer is the only way to solve it.

Comment: "Have you tried turning it on and back off again?"

Yeah a restart fixed it. Should have done that before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jumhyn, You should write the solution then by yourself and accept that answer and close it or accept this answer saying ... TRY TO RESTART YOUR COMPUTER :)